# What I supposed to do if Cronbach's alpha is negative?

Tags: spss, reliability, cronbachs-alpha

I have 100 sample with 8 questions with answers between Yes or No (Guttman scale). Cronbach's alpha is badly negative. I have checked everything I could think of, but the result did not change. I have already check the same questionnaire with differences translation and the value of Cronbach's alpha is > 0.6.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could have reverse coded items.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before and even published [a paper related to negative reliability estimates](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0013164411430225) (see the Appendix for a technical explanation of why this happens). In short, this can happen when total test variance is small. So, perhaps there's a ceiling or floor effect you're encountering. Are all individuals frequently answering the same?

Instead of computing $\alpha$, you might consider calculating McDonald's $\omega$, which seems to be less sensitive to this issue.

See also:

Krus, D. J., & Helmstadter, G. C. (1993). The problem of negative reliabilities. Educational & Psychological Measurement, 53(3), 643.

Reinhardt, B. M. (1991). Factors affecting coefficient alpha: A mini monte carlo study. (Paper presented at the Annual Meeting of the Southwest Educational Research Association, San
Antonio, TX, January 26, 1991)